# how to programmatically reject new connections on 4d v17?

Tags: 4d-database

are there commands similar to **WEB STOP SERVER** and **STOP SQL SERVER** but to reject new connections on my 4d server?

Comment: i wanted to do both actually. my goal is to prevent external operations to come into the server while i am performing some critical operations to avoid bringing an inconcistency somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found out that by using the **On Server Open Connection Database Method** , i can reject new connections by returning a value different than 0 as seen in the doc

> If you do not return a value in $0, thereby leaving the variable undefined or initialized to zero, 4D Server assumes that the database method accepts the connection. If you do not accept the connection, you return a non-null value in $0.

so i just change the return value **$0** under the conditions i need

```
If(*some conditions*)
  $0:1
End If
```